# How to load 2d array with consecutive numbers 0-99?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int z[10][10];
  int *myPtr2;
  int p;
  int q;
  myPtr2 = &(z[0][0]);

  //load 2d array
  for (p=0; p<10; p++) {
    for (q=0; q<10; q++) {
      *myPtr2 = q;
      myPtr2 ++;
    }
  }
```

My code results in 10 rows of numbers 0-9.

**These are my directions:**

Create a 2-dimensional integer array of size 10 by 10.

a.  Using a pointer load the array with consecutive numbers from 0 to 99.

b.  Create a pointer index that allows you write out a selected row.

c.  Create a function that writes out a single row.

d.  Write out the array starting from row 0 to row 9, by calling your function from item 2c.

e.  Using the pointer index from item 2b, exchange rows 0 and 9,  and rows 3 and 4.

f.  Make sure that your row exchanges worked by repeating step d.

Comment: `*myPtr2 = (p * 10) + q`

Answer (score 1):

The assigned value `q` only ranges from `0` to `9`, while it needs to go from `0` to `99`.

You need to change the assignment line to take into account the row:

```
*myPtr2 = q + (10*p); // 10 is the row width
```